# True Curves change to densified lines upon Topology validation. Fixing 500,000+ slivers in parcel layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlapping-features, parcel, slivers, gap

We are experiencing an issue as detailed by this technical article: [Bug: Curve features are converted to densified line segments from an arc in a SQL Server geodatabase after compression](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000017006).

We are using ArcMap 10.7.1 Advanced. We have talked to ESRI technical Support and, they feel, the problem should not be in our database now. We recently went through two upgrades, originally editing in 10.5.1 then upgraded quickly to 10.6 and finally upgrading to 10.7.1. The Problem could be due to the ArcMap upgrades which do not have patches for the problem that did have a software patch in 10.5

We have 500,000+ topology errors in our parcel layer, due to slivers and overlaps of the true curves being generalized to densified lines. Does anyone have a recommendation of automating all or part of the process of cleaning this up short of manually aligning to edge on every sliver?

See the example screenshot below, where the blue line represents the parcel line after being densified, and the red line is the line the polygons were built from. I need to realign the polygons(blue line) to the polygon line boundaries (red lines):

[image: Screenshot of parcel slivers]

Unfortunately, rebuilding the polygons from the lines is not an option as our cartography staff has made thousands of edits to attributes and geometry of the polygons in the last 6 months since this issue appeared. We would have to go back 7 months and attempt to track what polygons have been split, merged, reconfigured, resized, annexed, as well as trying to figure out what attributes changed and redo all of that.  We are not the primary editors to the tax parcel data.

We seek any ideas, resources, personal experience attempting a task like this, as this is a major issue for us. Fortunately, we believe we have stopped the process of creating these errors to begin with so no more slivers are being created, I just need to fix the 500,000+ that have already been created.

Comment: I'd convert polygons to edges, find pair to one blue (if any) that has same end points and replace geometry. Reduild polygons from new edges. Perhaps save attributes to points, inside.